# Lucene - string field which doesn't need to be indexed

Tags: java, lucene

(Currently using Lucene 4.6).

Just wondering why it appears sort of undesirable to store text info in an `org.apache.lucene.document.Document` which is not indexed.  `TextField` is indexed and tokenized.  `StringField` is indexed but not tokenized.

But supposing you just need a `String` which accompanies the other info in your `org.apache.lucene.document.Document`s but will itself never be the subject of a query?

It's just that (in 4.6) `org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Index` has a "NO", meaning "Do not index the field value.", but this is currently "Deprecated".

Why?  Is there a better way of having "inert" `String` info accompanying your indexed (and possibly tokenized) more significant fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Nearly) 2 years later and I hopefully have a slightly better understanding of things.

The answer to this appears to be to use `StoredField`.

In fact `TextField` and `StringField` are stored in and retrieved from indices as `StoredField`.  `StoredField` is "agnostic", as are `TextField` and `StringField`: all these are subclasses of `Field`, which has, among other methods, `setStringValue`, `setIntValue`, `stringValue` and `numericValue`!

With Lucene 6 there is no `IntField` ... but there is a "red herring" called `IntPoint`. It's a red herring because it cannot be stored in an index... ever!

In fact if you need to store an `Integer` you (I think) need to use either `StoredField` or (if it needs to be indexed) `StringField`.

See [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479862/595305).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#Field(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType)) for your field

```
Field(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType)
```

FieldType has [property](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html#indexed())

```
public void setIndexed(boolean value)
```

Or you can create you custom field, in which you override default constructor with need to your field type:

```
public final class StringNoIndexedField extends Field {
   public static final FieldType TYPE_NOT_INDEXED = new FieldType();
   static {
      TYPE_NOT_INDEXED.setIndexed(false);
      TYPE_NOT_INDEXED.setStored(true);
      TYPE_NOT_INDEXED.setTokenized(false);
      TYPE_NOT_INDEXED.freeze();
  }

  public StringNoIndexedField(String name, String value) {
    super(name, value, TYPE_NOT_INDEXED);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm a little confused about that byte array in your first solution... (where does it come from and what does it do?); also (unless I'm very slow, for which I apologise), in your second solution, shouldn't the name of the constructor be "StringNoIndexedField" rather than "StringField"... perhaps you'd care to change this if so???

Comment: Thanks for comments, you are right.  I had fixed this issue.