# IntPoint is not indexing integer values

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

While we're trying to index integer values with the Field Type "IntPoint", the values seem to be not transferred correctly into our Lucene Index.

We are working with Lucene 6.0.

According to the Lucene documention the code snippet:

```
        doc.add(new IntPoint(LENGTH2, 17));
```

should add the LENGTH2 document field with the Value "17" to our indexable document.
Unfortunately, there are no values in our index field LENGHT2.

We also tried this with the deprecated Field Type "LegacyIntField". With this Type we got some cryptic smybols in our index field like:

```
        950 length  h(5j
        950 length  pT
        950 length  xj
        950 length  `PkU2
```

For this type we used the following code:

```
        LegacyIntField intField = new LegacyIntField(LENGTH,0,Field.Store.NO);
        intField.setIntValue(17);
        doc.add(intField);
```

Do you know a solution for this problem?

**Addition:**
Do you have an working example, which includes the indexing and searching of IntPoint?
We tried it out, but it seems to be not working.
[Java Code for Lucene IntPoint Indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwez2.png)

We also tried to do some search on this field. But the results didn't match with that what we expected.

```
   QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields,analyzer);
   Query query = parser.parse("content:" + queryString);

   Query queryNumeric = IntPoint.newRangeQuery(Indexer.LENGTH2, 0, 5);
   Builder builder = new Builder();
   builder.add(query, Occur.MUST);
   builder.add(queryNumeric, Occur.MUST);
   BooleanQuery booleanQ = builder.build();

   TopDocs hits2 = is.search(booleanQ, 1000);
   System.out.print("short: " + hits2.totalHits);
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides that you're indexing field as:

`doc.add(new IntPoint(LENGTH2, 17));`

You also need to store the field separately by adding separate instance of `StoredField`:

`doc.add(new StoredField(LENGTH2,17));`

According to the documentation of `IntPoint`

> An indexed int field for fast range filters. If you also need to store the value, you should add a separate StoredField instance.

Reference:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntPoint.html

Comment: Thank you sir. We added some new information to our post :).

Answer (score 3):

This Lucene 6+ class `IntPoint` (and related classes) seems to be rather poorly documented.

From my experiments it would appear that this is NOT a replacement of `IntField`, and that the latter always was a "fiction" and has just been dumped.

It appears that mostly people who want to store an `Integer` field in their Lucene `Documents` comprising an index should realise that in fact you'll be storing a **text representation** of this `Integer`.  Obviously the same applied with earlier versions of Lucene, with `IntField`: index files consist of bytes of text*.

For this reason, for simple storage of `Integer`s, you should just use a single field, of class `StoredField` or class `StringField`, and **not include an `IntPoint` field at all**.

**Recap**

- `TextField` is tokenised, indexed and stored.
- `StringField` is indexed and stored.
- `StoredField` is just stored.

Clearly tokenising a number is nonsensical.  Whether you use `StringField` or `StoredField` then depends on whether you need to ***index*** your number, or whether it is just an item of data contained in the `Document` which will be needed when the `Document` is retrieved.  Note that all these classes are subclasses of class `Field`, and inherit all its methods, including `setIntValue`.  All, despite the names `TextField` and `StringField`, are in fact therefore "polyvalent".

The proof that all this stored stuff is really just text is found when you do a search and get your `Document`s back: when you do

```
Field myRetrievedField = myRetrievedLDocument.getField( intFieldName )
```

what you get back is a `StoredField`... this is the same if you store a `TextField`: i.e. whatever the `Field` subclass you used to do the storing what is stored is a `StoredField`! And because a `StoredField` is indeed "polyvalent" you can then either go

```
myRetrievedField.numericValue()
```

or

```
myRetrievedField.stringValue()
```

The result from `numericValue()` is class `java.lang.Number` ... but said to be

> Non-null if this field has a numeric value

... i.e. `StoredField` obviously parses this returned text and tries to make it into a `Number`. If the text is not parsable as such you get back `null`.

Presumably the stored number is always stored as in "Anglo-Saxon" format: i.e. with dot for decimal point (unlike French: comma instead). If Lucene implemented some sort of "locale" setting with this regard it could certainly impair the compatibility/readability of retrieved `Document`s. French (and other) people who are dissatisfied with this cultural hegemony ([hégémonie culturelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9g%C3%A9monie_culturelle)), if such it be, always have the option of storing numbers as text with "decimal commas" etc. and then using `stringValue` instead of `numericValue` and parsing with their own parser!

But the main point is just that `IntPoint` has nothing to do with storing `Integer`s.

---

* It may be that in some Lucene implementations, past, present or future, that numbers are stored in a more compact way than just spelling them out using (one- byte UTF-8) `String`s.  This is because the number of possible characters is less than 256: less than 16, in fact: numbers 0 to 9, - (minus), ., space and "E" for exponential.  So in fact numbers could be stored in half the space of the equivalent `String`.  Whether Lucene currently bothers saving space in this way I have no idea but it could presumably be found out by getting `stringValue` on a retrieved `Field` which had been stored using `setIntValue`.